# Data structure with O(1) insertion and O(log(n)) search complexity?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there any data structure available that would provide *O(1)* -- i.e. constant -- insertion complexity and *O(log(n))* search complexity **even in the worst case**?

A sorted vector can do a *O(log(n))* search but insertion would take *O(n)* (taken the fact that I am not always inserting the elements either at the front or the back). Whereas a list would do *O(1)* insertion but would fall short of providing *O(log(n))* lookup.

I wonder whether such a data structure can even be implemented.

Comment: Any reason why hash tables would not be appropriate? Do you consider the possibility of collisions to be a factor not to count it as *O(1)* for these actions?

Comment: yes, there will be duplicates. So hash tables won't work right? I haven't thought of the size though, but consider it to be large enough.

Comment: "that depends" - on the meaning of "search", for one: find exact matches in what has been inserted before, or "smallest non-smaller". For exact match, you may get away with hashing&hand-waving (at collisions). The verb phrase in `such data structure even be implemented` is broken.

Comment: Hash works with duplicates, because you can maintain an occurrence count for each element in your hash table.

Comment: You can have both `O(1)` insertion and `O(1)` search if you are willing to consume an enormous amount of memory. Create a giant array the size of your key space. To insert, copy the item into the array at the position indexed by the kay. To look up, read from the array at the position indexed by the key. Each of these is an `O(1)` operation. However, the space requirements are huge if your key space is large.

Comment: I doubt that you can get that in the worst case, but hash tables can give you amortized `0(1)` for both insertion and search and will work well even with large data sets.

Comment: (Insertion will be at least as expensive as search because insertion must first search for the key in order to handle duplicates. So if you want `O(1)` insertion, you need to find something that gives you `O(1)` search. That significantly limits your options.)

Comment: Perhaps a data structure with `O(log(n))` insertion and search, which defers all insertions until searched? This is similar to what Tarjan's disjoint-set data structure does, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Rhymoid That wouldn't help, because inserting `n` items followed by a search will incur `O(n)` cost at the first search as it processes all the deferred insertions. You might be able to amortize that cost, but OP wants guaranteed `O(log n)` cost on search, not amortized cost.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `Insertion will be [as expensive because it] must first search for the key in order to handle duplicates` you seem to be considering _set_ (or do you include _multiset_?) - neither of which the question does mention (explicitly).

Comment: @RaymondChen `Insertion will be at least as expensive as search because insertion must first search for the key in order to handle duplicates`. That's not correct, consider for example Binomial Heaps, which have O(1) for insertion but O(log n) to find the minimum value and O(n) to find an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you would have to bend the rules a bit in two ways:

1) You could use a structure that has O(1) insertion and O(1) search (such as the [CritBit](https://cr.yp.to/critbit.html) tree, also called [bitwise trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries)) and add artificial cost to turn search into O(log n).

A critbit tree is like a binary [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) for bits. It stores keys by walking along the bits of a key (say 32bits) and use the bit to decide whether to navigate left ('0') or right ('1') at every node. The maximum complexity for search and insertion is both O(32), which becomes O(1).

2) I'm not sure that this is O(1) in a strict theoretical sense, because O(1) works only if we limit the value range (to, say, 32 bit or 64 bit), but for practical purposes, this seems a reasonable limitation.

Note that the perceived performance will be O(log n) until a significant part of the possible key permutations are inserted. For example, for 16 bit keys you probably have to insert a significant part of 2^16 = 65563 keys.

Answer (score 2):

**No** (at least in a model where the elements stored in the data structure can be compared for order only; hashing does not help for worst-case time bounds because there can be one big collision).

Let's suppose that every insertion requires at most c comparisons. (Heck, let's make the weaker assumption that n insertions require at most c*n comparisons.) Consider an adversary that inserts n elements and then looks up one. I'll describe an adversarial strategy that, during the insertion phase, forces the data structure to have Omega(n) elements that, given the comparisons made so far, could be ordered any which way. Then the data structure can be forced to search these elements, which amount to an unsorted list. The result is that the lookup has worst-case running time Omega(n).

The adversary's goal is to give away as little information as possible. Elements are sorted into three groups: winners, losers, and unknown. Initially, all elements are in the unknown group. When the algorithm compares two unknown elements, one chosen arbitrarily becomes a winner and the other becomes a loser. The winner is deemed greater than the loser. Similarly, unknown-loser, unknown-winner, and loser-winner comparisons are resolved by designating one of the elements a winner and the other a loser, without changing existing designations. The remaining cases are loser-loser and winner-winner comparisons, which are handled recursively (so the winners' group has a winner-unknown subgroup, a winner-winners subgroup, and a winner-losers subgroup). By an averaging argument, since at least n/2 elements are compared at most 2*c times, there exists a subsub...subgroup of size at least n/2 / 3^(2*c) = Omega(n). It can be verified that none of these elements are ordered by previous comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder whether such a data structure can even be implemented.

I am afraid the answer is no.

**Searching OK, Insertion NOT**

When we look at the data structures like Binary search tree, B-tree, Red-black tree and AVL tree, they have average search complexity of `O(log N)`, but at the same time the average insertion complexity is same as `O(log N)`. Reason is obvious, *the search will follow (or navigate through) the same pattern in which the insertion happens*.

**Insertion OK, Searching NOT**

Data structures like Singly linked list, Doubly linked list have average insertion complexity of `O(1)`, but again the searching in Singly and Doubly LL is painful `O(N)`, just because they *don't have any indexing based element access support*.

Answer to your question lies in the [Skiplist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) implementation, which is a linked list, still it needs `O(log N)` on average for insertion (when lists are expected to do insertion in `O(1)`).

On closing notes, Hashmap comes very close to meet the speedy search and speedy insertion requirement with the cost of huge space, but if *horribly* implemented, it can result into a complexity of `O(N)` for both insertion and searching.

Comment: (Re skip-list: the question explicitly asks _O(log(n))_ search complexity **even in the worst case**.)